# How to increase data samples to prevent over fitting?

Tags: dataset, overfitting

As you know increase a data samples on training is a way to preventing of over fitting.

I'm working on an UCI data set with 198 samples and 34 feature this is my data set's dimension and I wanted to know what's the meaning of increasing our data to prevent of over fitting, I mean I should make a change on selecting test and try data size or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working with a given data set, you can't increase the amount of data, so you will have to use simpler models.

How much simpler? That depends on the model. There are some rules of thumb, e.g., for linear regression you want at least 10 observations for each independent variable; for logistic regression you want at least 10 observations in the smallest class for each independent variable and so on, but they are only rules of thumb (and there are others that recommend different limits).

This isn't solvable by changing the train and test sizes as increasing the size of one will decrease the size of the other.

Comment: Will leave-one-out cross-validation indicate the degree of "overfitting"?

Answer (score 1):

It means literally going and getting more data. As in I took a survey of 100 people, and then decided I needed more data so I surveyed 50 more.
If you’re using UCI data, increasing your sample is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If it's classification problem you can try to resample the data. Here's a [lib](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn) with most of the popular methods.